# How to extract spaced numbers from a string into a float array only using 1D array?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 20

int main()
{
  int num;
  float val[SIZE];
  int size_r;
  int size_j;
  int size;
  int i=0;
  int j;
  char mat[SIZE];
  int key;

  printf("Enter size of rows: ");
  scanf("%i",&size_r);
  getchar();
  printf("Enter size of columns: ");
  scanf("%i",&size_j);
  getchar();
  size=size_r*size_j;

  printf("Please input matrix (one row at a time and spaced numbers): ");
  for (num=0;num<size_r;num++)
  {
    fgets(mat,SIZE,stdin);
    for (num=0;num<SIZE;num++)
    {
      if (mat[num]==' ')
      {
         val[i]=atof(mat);
         i++;
      }
    }
  }
  for (num=0;num<SIZE;num++)
  {
    printf("%.2f\t",val[num]);
  }
```

I have initialized some variables that I will need, but the code is not complete yet because of the following problem. For example, when I input '12 23 34', I can only extract 12.00 and every other element fills with 0.00. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The description is a bit confusing, so I will point out a few problems that I clearly see with your code.

Here is the definition of how atof works:

"Parses the C string str, interpreting its content as a floating point number and returns its value as a double.

The function first discards as many whitespace characters (as in isspace) as necessary until the first non-whitespace character is found. Then, starting from this character, takes as many characters as possible that are valid following a syntax resembling that of floating point literals (see below), and interprets them as a numerical value. The rest of the string after the last valid character is ignored and has no effect on the behavior of this function.
"

Understanding the last sentence of the definition is the key to understanding your problem.

The reason you are getting the output 12.00 every time is because of the following:
When you reach the first space and call atof(), the atof function sees the characters: 12+ space and thus the 12 is extracted and is converted to Float.

The subsequent time you find a space, the function sees 12(space)23(space) and the (23 space) segment is ignored.  Each subsequent iteration of the loop atof will only return 12.0000.

To resolve the problem you need to define a char pointer that initially is set to the first digit of mat,  chrPtr = mat.  subsequently when you find a space you perform the atof on the char ptr  = val[i] = atof(chrNum);

You then need to bump the char ptr to the space preceeding the next numerical character 
chrNum = strchr(mat, ' ');

You also have to be careful when you get to the last number as there is no more white spaces, but a carriage return '\n'. This case also has to be dealed with.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you are asking, there are several areas of obvious confusion. The first surrounds `SIZE` and `size`. If you are asking for both `size_r` and `size_j`, then `SIZE` is just the array limit you check to see if your `val[SIZE]` can hold `size_r * size_j` elements. You cannot use `SIZE` as an iteration limit in this case.

However, if you only input one value (e.g. either `size_r` or `size_j`, but not both), then you can use `SIZE` to fix the non-entered value. `SIZE / size_r` to fix `size_j`) You would of course still have to insure that *integer division* did not result in fixing a greater size than elements.

Next, there is no magic simulating a 2D matrix with a 1D array of values. You can find a lot of literature discussing the *stride* (or number of columns) used to index a 2D matrix from a 1D array. Your array indexes to simulate a 2D array can be handled as follows (print example):

```
for (i = 0; i < size_r; i++) {   /* output your values in 2D format */
    for (j = 0; j < size_j; j++)
        printf ("%7.2f", val[i * size_j + j]);
    putchar ('\n');    /* for your newline */
}
```

Essentially, you are simulating the following 2D array:

```
array[i * size_j][j];
```

Putting all the pieces together, and noting there is no need to fill an array of `strings` before conversion to `float`, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 20

int main (void)
{
    int size_r, size_j, size, i, j;
    float val[SIZE];

    printf ("Enter size of rows: ");
    if (scanf ("%d", &size_r) != 1) {   /* always validate input */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid conversion for rows.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("Enter size of columns: ");
    if (scanf ("%d", &size_j) != 1) {   /* ditto */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid conversion for rows.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    size = size_r * size_j; /* compute the requires size of array */

    /* you can only use SIZE as a limit unless you only ask for a row   */
    if (size > SIZE) {  /* or col, and set the other with e.g. SIZE/row */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: SIZE (%d) insufficient to hold "
                            "size (%d) elements.\n", SIZE, size);
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("Please input matrix (one row at a time and spaced numbers): ");
    for (i = 0; i < size_r; i++)     /* your indexing is: array[i*size_j][j] */
        for (j = 0; j < size_j; j++)
            if (scanf ("%f", &val[i * size_j + j]) != 1) {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: conversion for val[%d][%d] failed.\n",
                        i * size_j, j);
                return 1;
            }
    putchar ('\n');     /* just to make it look nice piping input to it */

    for (i = 0; i < size_r; i++) {   /* output your values in 2D format */
        for (j = 0; j < size_j; j++)
            printf ("%7.2f", val[i * size_j + j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Specifying `5-rows` and `4-columns`, and entering values `1.0 ... 20.0`, you can simulate a nice `5x4` matrix from the 1D array `val`:

```
$ echo 5 4 {1..20}.0 | ./bin/spcarrayfloats
Enter size of rows: Enter size of columns: Please input matrix <snip>:
   1.00   2.00   3.00   4.00
   5.00   6.00   7.00   8.00
   9.00  10.00  11.00  12.00
  13.00  14.00  15.00  16.00
  17.00  18.00  19.00  20.00
```

Lastly, always, ALWAYS, check the return of whatever function you are using to take user input, and then *validate* the value entered is within your usable range. (a cat may be stepping on the keyboard for all you know). If you always validate your input (and compile with warnings enabled e.g. `-Wall -Wextra`), you will find that your debugging time is drastically reduced.

Look over all of the answers, and if I didn't understand exactly what you were looking for, just let me know in a comment.